# Consulta a SQLite no devuelve nada

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, funciones, sqlite3

Estoy escribiendo las funciones para manipular una base de datos. A pesar de que la consulta parece ser correcta, porque en mi DB Browser corre bien, en typescript me devuelve esto "Database {}" por consola

```
function Nombre_Producto(id:number){
    let sql : string = `SELECT Nombre FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE id='${id}';`;
    console.log(sql);
    let producto = db.run(sql);

    return producto;

}

let producto : any = Nombre_Producto(1);
console.log(producto);
```

Deberia devolverme un simple y comun string.

Comment: depende lo que devuelva db.run... y que sentido tiene usar any si es ts???

Comment: Porque me devuelve un objeto vacio que no se como manejar.

Comment: tal vez db.run te este devolviendo una promise? Proba con async/await.

Comment: Lo recibi como una promesa, asi: Nombre_Producto(1)
                                                      .then((producto) => {
                                                      console.log(producto);}) de todas formas me devuelve el: "Database {}"

Answer (score 2):

Si estas usando el paquete `sqlite` ([este](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite#getting-a-single-row)), entonces estas usando el metodo incorrecto, ya que `run` se utiliza para operaciones sin resultado de registros, como `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc.

Lo que debes usar es el metodo `get`, como se ve en su pagina. Que igual te paso:

```javascript
//Getting a single row

const result = await db.get('SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE col = ?', 'test')

// { col: 'test' }

const result = await db.get('SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE col = ?', ['test'])

// { col: 'test' }

const result = await db.get('SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE col = :test', {
  ':test': 'test'
})

// { col: 'test' }
```

Espero te sirva y puedas resolver. Saludos

Comment: Todavia me da el mismo resultado. Como deveria tratar el dato que devuelve esa consulta?

Comment: @FirielCasselius, puede proporcionar mas información de como tienes la tabla a nivel de Sqlite? y como generas la conexión a la base de datos, esto para tener mayor información lo que estas haciendo antes de consultar.